# Are weighted limits terminal in a category of cones?

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, enriched-category-theory

Consider a Benabou-cosmos $(\mathcal{V},\otimes,J)$, $\mathcal{V}$-categories $\mathcal{I},\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{V}$-functors $\mathcal{W}:\mathcal{I} \rightarrow \mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{D}:\mathcal{I} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. The usual definition of a $\mathcal{W}$-weighted limit of $\mathcal{D}$ is as a representing object of the functor
$$\tag{$\star$}[\mathcal{I,V}](\mathcal{W},\mathcal{C}(-,\mathcal{D})):\mathcal{C}^{op} \longrightarrow \mathcal{V}$$

While this certainly works fine and one can do amazing things with it, it completely hides the limit-cones I know and love, what made it hard for me to get a grasp of weighted limits. It took me some time to see that the cones are hidden in the points of the points of the functor: In any concrete example I could find a $\mathcal{V}$-natural transformation $\mathcal{W}(-) \Rightarrow \mathcal{C}(T,\mathcal{D}(-))$ describes a cone over the diagram $\mathcal{D}$ with tip $T$, whose legs are *enriched* by the corresponding weights of $\mathcal{W}$.

Ordinary conical limits can be characterized as terminal objects in the category of cones over a diagram, so the question in the title naturally comes to mind.

> Are weighted limits terminal in a category of cones?

Naively, the $\mathcal{V}$-category of cones should be something like the pullback
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\operatorname{Cone}(\mathcal{W},\mathcal{D})&\rightarrow&\mathcal{W}\,/\,[\mathcal{I,V}]\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
\mathcal{C}^{op} & \rightarrow & [\mathcal{I,V}]
\end{array}$$
where $\mathcal{W} \,/\, [\mathcal{I,V}]$ denotes the [enriched slice category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259829/enriched-slice-categories) and the lower $\mathcal{V}$-functor is given by $\mathcal{C}(-,\mathcal{D})$. Explicitly, the objects are $\mathcal{V}$-natural transformations $\mathcal{W}(-) \Rightarrow \mathcal{C}(T,\mathcal{D}(-))$ and the Hom-objects ought to be given by pullbacks
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\operatorname{Cone}(\mathcal{W},\mathcal{D})(\alpha,\beta)&\rightarrow&\mathcal{W}\,/\,[\mathcal{I,V}](\alpha,\beta)\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
\mathcal{C}^{op}(T,T') & \rightarrow & [\mathcal{I,V}](\mathcal{C}(T,\mathcal{D}-),\mathcal{C}(T',\mathcal{D}-))
\end{array}$$
(modulo some transposition of $T$ and $T'$ in case I made a mistake). I am fairly sure that this definition makes sense one way or another, but I don't see yet how to relate being terminal in this category with $\mathcal{V}$-representability of the functor ($\star$).

In fact, typing this up I start to doubt this is possible, since an object $X \in \mathcal{V}$ is in general **not** characterized by its points $J \rightarrow X$. And a $\mathcal{V}$-natural transformation is more or less nothing than a collection of such points $J \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{F}X,\mathcal{G}X)$, so why should we expect the functor $(\star)$ to be characterized by my construction of $\operatorname{Cone}(\mathcal{W,D})$?

On the other hand there might be some enriched *category of elements*/*Grothendieck-construction* business I am unaware of, which might make this work nonetheless. But for me, being new to enriched categories, this is rather hard to research. Hence I kindly ask for your help.

I hope this question is "research level" enough to be posted on MathOverflow and if it is not I will gladly move this over to Mathematics Stack Exchange. This way or another I really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: Fosco Loregian and I have been working on a notion of "W-weighted natural transformation", which comes together with a notion of "W-co/cone". Using those, one can rephrase the definition of a weighted limit as a pair $(\lim^{[W]}(D),\lambda)$ consisting of an object $\lim^{[W]}(D)$ together with a W-cone $\lambda\colon\Delta_{\lim^{[W]}(D)}\overset{W}{\Rightarrow}D$ for which the natural transformation
$$\lambda_*\circ\Delta_{(-),\lim^{[W]}(D)}\colon h_{\lim^{[W]}(D)}\Rightarrow\mathsf{Nat}^{[W]}(\Delta_{(-)},D)$$
is a natural isomorphism. ([1/n])

Comment: (IIRC this requires enriching over $\mathsf{CoMon}(\mathcal{V})$ rather than $\mathcal{V}$, but this is satisfied in many cases of interest, such as $\mathcal{V}=\mathsf{Cats}$, $\mathcal{V}=\mathsf{Spaces}$, or any Cartesian monoidal category. (There are also things like enrichments of algebras in coalgebras via Sweedler homs))

Comment: This restores a bit the picture of limit cones, but I think terminality is trickier, there being multiple notions of terminality in enriched categories (see Section 4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.07843)).

Comment: (E.g. here are four different definitions for an object $X$ of a V-category $\mathcal{C}$ to be terminal: 1) For all $A\in C$ the hom-object $\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,A)$ is terminal in $V$ 2) For all $A\in C$, we have $\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,A)=\mathbf{1}_V$; 3) The projection $U\colon\mathcal{C}_{/X}\to\mathcal{C}$ is an isomorphism of $V$-categories 4) $U$ is an equivalence)

Comment: I think the main problem is the one you noted, that morphisms $1_X\to X$ of V don't determine $X$. (You can indeed set up an enriched category of elements construction, and then one can show (after some work) that if $1_V$ has no non-trivial endomorphisms, then an object $\pi\colon h_X\Rightarrow\mathcal{F}$ of $\int^C_V\mathcal{F}$ is terminal iff the map $\pi_*\colon\mathrm{Hom}_V(1_V,h_X(A))\to\mathrm{Hom}_V(1_V,\mathcal{F}(A))$ is a bijection of sets for all $A$.)

Comment: (However, this is very far from implying $h_X\cong F$, which one could otherwise use to characterise enriched limits as terminal co/cones... For enrichment in $\mathsf{Cats}$ [the situation is better, though](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16394))

Comment: @Emily thank you very much for your comments and apologies for my late reply. The W-natural transformations sound fun, I will look into it. A terminal object, ought to be a weighted limit of the empty diagram, so is there really this ambiguity? The restriction that $1_V$ shouldn't have nontrivial endomorphisms immediately turns $\mathsf{Ab}$-enriched categories into a counterexample (doesn't it?), which I find a pity. But thank you anyway for giving me these insights into the category of elements perspective!

Comment: It's my pleasure! (And no worries :)

Comment: Regarding terminal objects, I think it depends on which definition of terminality you take as "fundamental". Each of the four ones above agree for ordinary categories, but diverge in general for enriched categories. Nevertheless, they each have their uses. (They are at least closely related: e.g. if we start with a $\mathcal{V}_{/1_V}$-category $C$ and require again the annoying assumption on endomorphisms of $1_V$ being trivial, then $C_{/X}\to C$ being an iso. of $\mathcal{V}_{/1_V}$-categories is equivalent to asking that $\mathbf{Hom}_{C}(A,X)\cong 1_V$ for each $A\in\mathrm{Obj}(C)$)

Comment: The restriction on $1_V$ does rule out $\mathsf{Ab}$-enrichment. I've been suspecting for a while that maybe we can improve this situation if instead we started with internal categories (so for $\mathsf{Ab}$ we'd have not only a set of objects, but an abelian group of them) or some similar structure, though I still haven't explored this idea much...

Comment: By the way, I forgot to mention, but I think you might like this paper: [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.01313). It is the special case of your question for enrichment in categories and ordinary (i.e. unweighted) 2-limits, and shows that 2-terminality is too weak to recover 2-limits in general. The [other paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16394) I mentioned came after this one, and shows that there's however a different notion of 2-terminality, similar to the one above involving the projection $C_{/X}\to C$, that works!

Comment: Thanks again for these nice comments. The thing about internal categories is that they don't arise as often as enriched categories do (or do they?). Anyway your discussion makes me realise that *representability* and *initiality / terminality* cannot be used as interchangably as ordinary category theory might suggest, with representability being the more robust notion (in the sense of working in all contexts: ordinary, enriched, higher, internal) if I am not mistaken...

Comment: It's my pleasure :) I think enriched categories are definitely more common in practice, so we are really stuck with terminality being somewhat unsatisfying for enriched categories. I think representability is definitely more robust (though I wonder if maybe it's only because of morphisms $1_V\to X$ not determining $X$: would terminality work out fine if we modified the definition of the enriched slice $\mathcal{C}_{/X}$ to include also objects of the form $V\to\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,X)$ for all $V\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathcal{V})$, rather than just $1_V\to\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,X)$?)

Comment: (I think this would require $V$ to be a monoid in $\mathcal{V}$ for we to be able to define identities and composition, so maybe there's really no way out :/... In any case, this doesn't seem like a very nice object to work with!)